# Cross device user tracking

Tags: facebook, deep-linking, user-tracking, facebook-pixel

Let's say I have a facebook campaign displayed on mobile device, which leads to conversion (android application installed, it's deeplinked). Now the same user opens my webpage (with facebook pixel) on his desktop computer and buys some stuff there.

I would like to track that conversion was initiated by that campaign - with some external tool (mixpanel, exponea...). Is this possible? Is facebook pixel the right way to achieve this?

The user is not logged in, just on facebook on his device and his desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mixpanel library to track the user events in different platform. The distinct id in mixpanel maintain the cross device user tracking whenever you login with same user.

Comment: yes, the same i can do now with actually used tracking service (infinario). but you need to have logged in user for that. i need to track unlogged users.

Comment: If you are logged in and later logged out then the mixpanel distinct id is stored in browser cookie. So whenever user visits site (not logged in) it is tracked. But if you try in private window or clear cookie then it won't work.

Comment: i cant rely on that, only what i can count with is facebook.